# How to delete consecutive duplicates in a list of lists efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I have a nested list:

```
l = [['GILTI', 'was', 'intended', 'to','to', 'stifle', 'multinationals'. 'was'],
    ['like' ,'technology', 'and', 'and','pharmaceutical', 'companies', 'like']]
```

How can I detect two consecutive elements and delete one without using set or another similar operation? This should be the **desired output**:

```
l = [['GILTI', 'was', 'intended','to', 'stifle', 'multinationals'. 'was'],
    ['like' ,'technology', 'and','pharmaceutical', 'companies', 'like']]
```

I tried using itertools groupby like this:

```
from itertools import groupby  
[i[0] for i in groupby(l)]
```

And also, an ordered dict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

temp_lis = []
for x in l:
    temp_lis.append(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x)))
temp_lis
```

out:

```
[['GILTI', 'was', 'intended', 'to', 'stifle', 'multinationals'],
 ['like', 'technology', 'and', 'pharmaceutical', 'companies']]
```

The second solution might look that works well. However,it is wrong because it is deleting non consecutive repeated elements (eg was and like). How can I get the above **desired output**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` like so:

```
[[k for k, g in groupby(x)] for x in l]
```

This will keep one if there are multiple repeating consecutive elements.

In case you need to completely remove repetitive consecutive elements, use:

```
[[k for k, g in groupby(x) if len(list(g)) == 1] for x in l]
```

**Example**:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [['GILTI', 'was', 'intended', 'to','to', 'stifle', 'multinationals', 'was'],
    ['like' ,'technology', 'and', 'and','pharmaceutical', 'companies', 'like']]

print([[k for k, g in groupby(x)] for x in l])

# [['GILTI', 'was', 'intended', 'to', 'stifle', 'multinationals', 'was'],
#  ['like', 'technology', 'and', 'pharmaceutical', 'companies', 'like']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help again! What about a more particular solution? what if im just interested in removing ` 'to','to'` sequences?

Comment: @aywoki, so you don't want both `'to'`s?

Comment: yes im just curios about how to iterate in that case. This solution solves the problem though

Answer (score 2):

A custom generator solution:

```
def deduped(seq):
    first = True
    for el in seq:
        if first or el != prev:
            yield el
            prev = el
            first = False

[list(deduped(seq)) for seq in l]
# => [['GILTI', 'was', 'intended', 'to', 'stifle', 'multinationals', 'was'], 
#     ['like', 'technology', 'and', 'pharmaceutical', 'companies', 'like']]
```

EDIT: The previous version couldn't handle `None` being the first element.

Comment: `prev = object()` sentinel would also solve the first element issue

Answer (score 1):

- [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) -  method adds a counter to an iterable and returns it in a form of enumerate object.

**Ex.**

```
l = [['GILTI', 'was', 'intended','to', 'stifle', 'multinationals','was'],
    ['like' ,'technology', 'and','pharmaceutical', 'companies', 'like']]
result = []

for sublist in l:
    new_list = []
    for index,x in enumerate(sublist):
        #validate current and next element of list is same 
        if len(sublist)-1 >= index+1 and x == sublist[index+1]:
            continue
        #append none consecutive into new list
        new_list.append(x)
    #append list into result list
    result.append(new_list)

print(result)
```

**O/P:**

```
[['GILTI', 'was', 'intended', 'to', 'stifle', 'multinationals', 'was'], 
['like', 'technology', 'and', 'pharmaceutical', 'companies', 'like']]
```